# Android app runs on tablet as a small screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I made this android app with minSdkVersion "8" and targetSdkVersion "17" running on Froyo 2.2 or above. I have to run it on a samsung galaxy tab 2 for an assignment but is not displayed full screen. Its displayed on the upper left corner of the screen using about the 1/4 of the total screen.  I already tried the  commands and also the layout-large and layout-xlarge folders. My icons are included in all drawable folders. Anybody knows how can I fix it??

Comment: Is it displayed full-screen on smaller devices?

Comment: Can you post your layout XML?

Comment: are you using fixed width or height?

Comment: to codeMagic: i don't have any smaller android devices to check it out but on the emulator works perfect.

Comment: to ianhanniballake: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".UnitConverterMainActivity" >

Comment: to madlymad: i havent changed the default settings but i tried changing the dimension.xml but is just changing the margins.